Free offline plagiarism checker
Minimum requirements:

process plain text files (TXT)
works on English text
works on German text
free (as in beer, open source preferred)
works offline, no Internet connection
works on Windows (10, x64)

Optional:

process Word documents
process LaTeX documents
process PDF files


An offline would require to download the whole "knowledge base" to a local PC and then periodically receive updates for this knowledge base to add new publications. Do don't think that there is a commercial tool working this way as it would allow to "steal" the knowledge base thus the most valuable asset such a company has as it requires quite a bit of work to build and maintain it. Or do you search for a pure tool where you can build your own database?

@Robert I don't want to build my own database. Stealing the knowledge could be prevented by other means, I guess. Ideally it would be open source anyway and it uses papers that are freely available.
